# Getting an formula parse error on a basic if statement

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, localization, nested-if, ifs

I am  trying to use IF statement in a Google Sheet, but whatever I am  typing in the IF I am always getting a [formula parse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOwSu.png). Do I have to activate something, or am I missing something ?
A1 & B1 have the same type (integer)
I have no idea why.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `,` use `;` - this should solve your issue asap

Comment: Thanks, everywhere they are using coma why do I have to use ";" ?

Comment: @JeremyL. because your sheet is not english. if you want to use a comma go to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3La4.png and change the country to some english one